# Comparing an array with a nested array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays, One is `accounts` and another one is `departments`.

**Requirement:**

-> Need to compare both array and need to get the filtered **accounts** array.

-> Accounts array is single level whereas departments array has two level and I am in the need to compare a value of `JobTitleID` both in accounts and department.

-> And finally return the modified accounts array with filtered data.

```js
const accounts = [
  {
    "AccountId": 25205,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 250
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25206,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 253
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25232,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 257
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25233,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 261
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25236,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 256
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25237,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 255
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25245,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 281
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25246,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 279
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25265,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 362
  }
]




const departments = [
  {
    "deptName": "Production",
    "jobTitles": [
      {
        "JobTitleID": 246,
        "DepartmentID": 72,
        "JobName": "Department Foreman"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 357,
        "DepartmentID": 72,
        "JobName": "Maintenance Supervisor"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 247,
        "DepartmentID": 72,
        "JobName": "Production Manager"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 362,
        "DepartmentID": 72,
        "JobName": "Safety & Compliance Supervisor"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "deptName": "Engineering",
    "jobTitles": [
      {
        "JobTitleID": 250,
        "DepartmentID": 73,
        "JobName": "Architect"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 248,
        "DepartmentID": 73,
        "JobName": "CAD Operator"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 249,
        "DepartmentID": 73,
        "JobName": "Engineering Manager"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 251,
        "DepartmentID": 73,
        "JobName": "Professional Engineer"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "deptName": "Purchasing",
    "jobTitles": [
      {
        "JobTitleID": 253,
        "DepartmentID": 74,
        "JobName": "Purchasing Agent"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 255,
        "DepartmentID": 74,
        "JobName": "Purchasing Manager"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 252,
        "DepartmentID": 74,
        "JobName": "Yard Foreman"
      }
    ]
  }
]





const filteredData = accounts.map(item => {
   departments.map(levelOne => {
       levelOne.jobTitles.map(levelTwo => {
          return levelTwo.JobTitleID === item.JobTitleID
     })
  })              
})

console.log('filteredData ', filteredData)
```

**Expected Solution:**

```
[
  {
    "AccountId": 25205,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 250
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25206,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 253
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25237,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 255
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25265,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 362
  }
]
```

**Things I have tried:**

```
const filteredData = accounts.map(item => {
   departments.map(levelOne => {
       levelOne.jobTitles.map(levelTwo => {
          return levelTwo.JobTitleID === item.JobTitleID
     })
  })              
})
```

But I believe my approach is entirely a wrong one.. Kindly please help me to achieve the expected solution by comparing two arrays.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array of all the jobs in the `departments` array and then filter the `accounts` array using [`.some(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the specific job exist in the previously generated array. Here is an example:

```js
const accounts = [
  {
    "AccountId": 25205,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 250
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25206,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 253
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25232,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 257
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25233,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 261
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25236,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 256
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25237,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 255
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25245,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 281
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25246,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 279
  },
  {
    "AccountId": 25265,
    "CandidateID": 8474,
    "JobTitleID": 362
  }
]




const departments = [
  {
    "deptName": "Production",
    "jobTitles": [
      {
        "JobTitleID": 246,
        "DepartmentID": 72,
        "JobName": "Department Foreman"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 357,
        "DepartmentID": 72,
        "JobName": "Maintenance Supervisor"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 247,
        "DepartmentID": 72,
        "JobName": "Production Manager"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 362,
        "DepartmentID": 72,
        "JobName": "Safety & Compliance Supervisor"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "deptName": "Engineering",
    "jobTitles": [
      {
        "JobTitleID": 250,
        "DepartmentID": 73,
        "JobName": "Architect"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 248,
        "DepartmentID": 73,
        "JobName": "CAD Operator"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 249,
        "DepartmentID": 73,
        "JobName": "Engineering Manager"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 251,
        "DepartmentID": 73,
        "JobName": "Professional Engineer"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "deptName": "Purchasing",
    "jobTitles": [
      {
        "JobTitleID": 253,
        "DepartmentID": 74,
        "JobName": "Purchasing Agent"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 255,
        "DepartmentID": 74,
        "JobName": "Purchasing Manager"
      },
      {
        "JobTitleID": 252,
        "DepartmentID": 74,
        "JobName": "Yard Foreman"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const jobs = departments.reduce((a, c) => (a.concat(c.jobTitles)), []);
const results = accounts.filter(account => jobs.some(job => job.JobTitleID === account.JobTitleID));

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get an optimize solution using `Set object`. Set object stores only unique values of any type. First, get all the unique JobTitleID using set object from `departments` array. Then use `Array.prototype.filter()` method to filter the `accounts` array to get the result.

```js
const accounts = [
  {
    AccountId: 25205,
    CandidateID: 8474,
    JobTitleID: 250,
  },
  {
    AccountId: 25206,
    CandidateID: 8474,
    JobTitleID: 253,
  },
  {
    AccountId: 25232,
    CandidateID: 8474,
    JobTitleID: 257,
  },
  {
    AccountId: 25233,
    CandidateID: 8474,
    JobTitleID: 261,
  },
  {
    AccountId: 25236,
    CandidateID: 8474,
    JobTitleID: 256,
  },
  {
    AccountId: 25237,
    CandidateID: 8474,
    JobTitleID: 255,
  },
  {
    AccountId: 25245,
    CandidateID: 8474,
    JobTitleID: 281,
  },
  {
    AccountId: 25246,
    CandidateID: 8474,
    JobTitleID: 279,
  },
  {
    AccountId: 25265,
    CandidateID: 8474,
    JobTitleID: 362,
  },
];

const departments = [
  {
    deptName: 'Production',
    jobTitles: [
      {
        JobTitleID: 246,
        DepartmentID: 72,
        JobName: 'Department Foreman',
      },
      {
        JobTitleID: 357,
        DepartmentID: 72,
        JobName: 'Maintenance Supervisor',
      },
      {
        JobTitleID: 247,
        DepartmentID: 72,
        JobName: 'Production Manager',
      },
      {
        JobTitleID: 362,
        DepartmentID: 72,
        JobName: 'Safety & Compliance Supervisor',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    deptName: 'Engineering',
    jobTitles: [
      {
        JobTitleID: 250,
        DepartmentID: 73,
        JobName: 'Architect',
      },
      {
        JobTitleID: 248,
        DepartmentID: 73,
        JobName: 'CAD Operator',
      },
      {
        JobTitleID: 249,
        DepartmentID: 73,
        JobName: 'Engineering Manager',
      },
      {
        JobTitleID: 251,
        DepartmentID: 73,
        JobName: 'Professional Engineer',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    deptName: 'Purchasing',
    jobTitles: [
      {
        JobTitleID: 253,
        DepartmentID: 74,
        JobName: 'Purchasing Agent',
      },
      {
        JobTitleID: 255,
        DepartmentID: 74,
        JobName: 'Purchasing Manager',
      },
      {
        JobTitleID: 252,
        DepartmentID: 74,
        JobName: 'Yard Foreman',
      },
    ],
  },
];

const set = new Set();
departments.forEach((x) => x.jobTitles.forEach((y) => set.add(y.JobTitleID)));
const ret = accounts.filter((x) => set.has(x.JobTitleID));
console.log(ret);
```